# How to use ff package in a simple 'for' loop for a large dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some basic calculations with a large table (~94 million rows, 3 columns) that require the use of a package like ff in R. However, I'm having trouble using this package and running out of memory, though I know my computer is more than capable of handling this. I'm including my hardware/software specs below, as well as my code that doesn't seem to be using the ff package properly. I've spent over 100 hours reading every pdf, ppt, and website that mentions anything on the ff package, and I haven't found anything that explains how to use ff clearly (at least to an amateur like me). Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. This logic seems to work when I count up to about 1.1 million rows, but then it seems to go out of bounds after that.

I have also tried breaking up the 'for' loop into chunks 1/200 of the total size; creating new ff objects for existing ShortPrice & LongPrice ff files on each pass of the loop, then rm(), gc() at the end of each pass. When I create the ff files for each column through read.table.ffdf at the beginning, for some reason I lose the TradePosition values when trying to create a new ff object to the existing TradePosition ff file using vmode = "quad", "integer" or "raw".

Hardware/Software Specs:

- June 2012 Macbook Pro with 16 GB RAM, i7 Quad-Core Processor, 512 GB SSD
- OS X 10.8.2
- Using 32-bit R program

Data/Tables:

- Text file named "Trades.txt" has 94,741,221 rows, three columns
- Column 1 named TradePosition ("factor" type, levels/values = "0", "Short" or "Long")
- Column 2 named ShortPrice ("double" type, values represent EUR/USD currency prices to 5 decimal places)
- Column 3 named LongPrice ("double" type, values represent EUR/USD currency prices to 5 decimal places)
- Internal R variable "DatasetLength" = 94,741,221

Code:

```
library(ff)
options("fftempdir"="/Users/neil/Code/","ffbatchbytes"=20*getOption("ffbatchbytes"),"ffmaxbytes"=8*getOption("ffmaxbytes"),"ffpagesize"=1000*65536,"ffcaching"="mmnoflush")
ffdfTrades <- read.table.ffdf(file="/Users/neil/Code/Trades.txt",nrows=DatasetLength,FUN="read.table",header=TRUE,sep=";",quote="",colClasses=c("factor","numeric","numeric"),comment.char="")

Transactions <- c(rep(0,DatasetLength))
dataindex <- 1
for (dataindex in seq(1,DatasetLength-1,1)) {

    if (ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex]!=ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex+1]) {

        if (ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex+1]=="Short") {

            if (ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex]=="Long") {
                Transactions[dataindex+1] <- -2*ffdfTrades$ShortPrice[dataindex+1]
            }

            else {
                Transactions[dataindex+1] <- -1*ffdfTrades$ShortPrice[dataindex+1]
            }
        }

        else {

            if (ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex+1]=="Long") {

                if (ffdfTrades$TradePosition[dataindex]=="Short") {
                    Transactions[dataindex+1] <- 2*ffdfTrades$LongPrice[dataindex+1]
                }

                else {
                    Transactions[dataindex+1] <- 1*ffdfTrades$LongPrice[dataindex+1]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    message(paste("Row ",dataindex," done.",sep=""))
    dataindex <- dataindex + 1
}
```

Comment: Personally I would recommend bigmemory and related packages [http://www.bigmemory.org/](http://www.bigmemory.org/)

Comment: Also try to avoid looping over 94,741,221 records. It will be very slow in R, no matter what you use (data.frame, ff, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

First remark: it is a pitty that you run a 32bit version of R if you have 16Gb of RAM, why not a 64 bit version to fully use it?

For your question: you are not using ff nor R appropriately as Henrico is pointing out. Looping over each row in R is just not the way to do things, not in ff, not in base R. You need to vectorise your code. I advise you to follow an R course which is not related to handling large data but to the basic concepts of R data handling.

Apart from that remark, here is what you are looking for in ff using some extra utilities in package ffbase. Mark that I didn't look at your exact specification of what to do with Short/Long and your multiplication, but the ffifelse can be changed according to your needs, as you would do with a normal ifelse in R's base package. 
Good luck in trying out ff.

```
size <- 1000000
trades <- data.frame(TradePosition = factor(sample(c("0","Short","Long"), size, replace=TRUE)), ShortPrice = rnorm(size), LongPrice = rnorm(size))
write.table(trades, file = "Trades.txt", sep=";", row.names=FALSE)

require(ff)
require(ffbase)
trades <- read.table.ffdf(file="Trades.txt", sep=";", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("factor","numeric","numeric"))
idx <- cumsum(ff(1, length=nrow(trades)))
idx <- ffwhich(idx, idx < nrow(trades))
trades$previousposition <- c(ff(factor(NA)), trades$TradePosition[idx])
yourmultiplier <- 2
yourothermultiplier <- -1
trades$transactions <- ffifelse(trades$TradePosition == "Long", 
                            ffifelse(trades$previousposition == "Short", yourmultiplier*trades$ShortPrice, trades$ShortPrice),
                            ffifelse(trades$previousposition == "Long", yourothermultiplier*trades$LongPrice, trades$LongPrice))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried this code out, changing the ffifelse slightly for my purposes, and it does not work. I'm not sure why you're using cumsum() or ffwhich(). I understand you're trying to create a similar vector PreviousPosition to TradePosition, then use the ffifelse to compare them instead of doing anything row by row. What purpose do the two idx statements serve to that end? Note that all vectors are in chronological order. In this analysis, each row in Transaction is dependent on a row by row evaluation of TradePosition, ShortPrice and LongPrice.

Comment: The idx statements only serve to create trades$previousposition <- c(NA, trades$TradePosition[1:(nrow(trades)-1)]). The rest are just basic ifelse statements. See ?ifelse. ?ffifelse is the same but for ff vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Here are links to (IMHO superb) slides discribing how to use big data in R.

http://www.bytemining.com/2010/07/taking-r-to-the-limit-part-i-parallelization-in-r/
http://www.bytemining.com/2010/08/taking-r-to-the-limit-part-ii-large-datasets-in-r/

Both are from talks given to R User groups and detail different approaches on handling large data sets. They focus on bigmemory, but ff is also featured.

I, like some the commenters before, prefer the bigmemory approach. Mainly, because it is easier to find usable documentation. Specifically, working through the airline data example from the slides above is rather eye opening.

Then instead of brute forcing it, depending on your scenario, also trying a large sample of your 95 million rows might suffice to arrive at meaningful conclusions.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use bigmemory. Unfortunately I have a variable TradePosition that is a factor with possible values ("0","Short","Long"). I suppose I could convert these values to integer representations (e.g. 0,1,2) and use bigmemory instead. If I can't get this factor to work in ff then I will try that approach.